# LINQ: Looking for an idea

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-3.5

I started with LINQ and here's a snippet of my code.

```
var filterList = new List<string>()
            {
                "ACRating",
                "Axles",
                "SafetyCodes",
                "BuiltInFeatures"
            }

foreach( var i in filterList )
{
  var filter = i;
  var xList = Vehicles.FilterSpecList( filter );

  foreach ( var j in xList )
  {
    if ( xList.Count() == 1 ) /*Will Not Work since a list could have a single value.*/
    {
      switch( j.FeatureName )
      {                 
        case "ACRating":
          v.AcRating = j.Value;
          Console.WriteLine( j );
          break;
       }
    }
    else
    {
      switch( j.FeatureName )
      {
        //Am trying to still figure out how to get all the items in BuiltInFeatures, but you get the idea.
        case "BuiltInFeatures"
        {
          v.BuiltInFeatures = "MP3" + "SUNROOF";
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The issue I am facing is that xList.Count is not a reliable way of looking at list values. Is there some method where I can somehow mark the items in the filterlist as being a list v/s being a single value. So when I do a comparison in the code, I don't have to rely on xList.Count.

Comment: I wonder if it is easier to build a dictionary instead of a list to define the filters.

Comment: I'm not sure where you are trying to go with this code? What is xList? Why do you need the "Count() == 1" check?

Comment: @DaveShaw. There are two types of items that being returned by the VehicleFilter class. These items are in a list. The duplicate items are a list. The single items are properties. So for example teh list would contain one ore more items tagged as "BuiltInFeatures". That would get processed as a list. If the list contains a single item, it would get assigned to a property.

Comment: Ah I See :) Let me think 2 mins

Comment: What exactly is your return type for Vehicles.FilterSpecList()? The use of var in most of your sample should be explicitly declared since there is no easily identifiable implicit type that we mere mortals can identify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a possible answer.
This is the change I have in mind. The reason I am answering instead of commenting is lack of space in comments.

I hope I have closed all the braces correctly.

```
var filterList = new Dictionary<string, string>
                               {
                                    {"ACRating", "Property"},
                                    {"Axles", "Property"}
                                    {"SafetyCodes","List"}
                                    {"BuiltInFeatures","List"}
                               };   

                foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> i in filterList)
                {
                    var filter = i.Key;
                    var xList = Vehicles.FilterSpecList(filter);
                    if (i.Value == "List")
                    {
                        foreach (var j in xList)
                        {
                            switch(j.FeatureName)
                            {
                            case "BuiltInFeatures"
                            {
                                    v.BuiltInFeatures = "x," + "y";
                                    break;
                            }
                    }
                    else if(i.Value == "Property")
                    {
                foreach (var j in xList)
                        {
                        switch(j.FeatureName)
                            {                   
                                case "ACRating":
                                    v.AcRating = j.Value;
                                    Console.WriteLine(j.ToString());
                                    break;
                            }
                    }
```

**Improvements welcome.**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Sample App I knocked up in LinqPad:
M is whatever type your xList is. You could extend it if you need more stuff.
I'm sure there are more fluent solutions than this, but I don't have much knowledge of your project this is the best I can do... :)

```
class M
{
    public String FeatureName;
    public IEnumerable<String> Value;
}

M FilterSpecList(String filterName)
{
    if (filterName == "ACRating")
        return new M {FeatureName = "ACRating", Value = new [] {"OK",}};
    else if (filterName == "BuiltInFeatures")
        return new M {FeatureName = "BuiltInFeatures", Value = new[] {"MP3", "Sunroof",}};
    else
        return new M();//throw new Exception("More..");
}

void Main()
{
    List<String> filterList = new List<String>()
    {
        "ACRating",
        "Axles",
        "SafetyCodes",
        "BuiltInFeatures",
    };

    foreach (String filter in filterList)
    {
        var xList = FilterSpecList(filter);

        switch (xList.FeatureName)
        {
            case "ACRating":
                Console.WriteLine(xList.Value.Single());
                break;
            case "BuiltInFeatures":
                Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" + ", xList.Value));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still trying to figure out what is going on with the list.  However on first glance it appears that you could use `.ToLookUp()'`

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549073.aspx)

> The ToLookup(IEnumerable,
>   Func) method returns a
>   Lookup, a one-to-many
>   dictionary that maps keys to
>   collections of values. A Lookup differs from a
>   Dictionary, which
>   performs a one-to-one mapping of keys
>   to single values.
>
> The default equality comparer Default
>   is used to compare keys.